# Is this proof valid

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

This is a clear version of an earlier closed question.

Let: $x, u, y, v : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions in the complex variable $s=a+ib$ defined by convergente series. I have this implication:

If $x(s)=u(s), y(s)=v(s)$, then after some steps on these series one get an equation of the form: $h(s)=0$ which give one value of $s$ as $s=1+ib$ for some $b$.

I call this result ($s=1+ib$) as "(P)".

The function $h$ here depends on the given functions $x, u, y, v$. Its formula is not important.

let $A={s∈\mathbb{C}: x(s)=u(s),y(s)=v(s)}$ and $B= {s∈\mathbb{C}: x(s)=u(s)=y(s)=v(s)=0}$ is a proper subset of $A$.

I know that if $s∈A$ then (P) holds true.

My **question** is as follow: What happen if $s∈B$. Is (P) true or false!.

We remark here that if $s∈B$ then we cannot construct the function $h$ and hence we cannot deduce (P), i.e., if $x(s)=u(s)=y(s)=v(s)=0$ then I cannot do anything and the proof stoped here.

Comment: If $s\in B$, then $s\in A$, as $B$ is a subset of $A$. So (P) must be true. However, if you cannot construct the function $h$ for $s\in B$, then (P) makes no sense in this case and can't be true, and therefore it doesn't follow from $s\in A$ either.

Comment: French *valable* is English *valid*.

Comment: I can't tell without knowing the formula for $h$, but my guess would be you need to additionally require that some function of $x,u,y,v$ is non-zero in the definition of $A$, thus excluding some points of $B$.

Comment: if $x(s)=u(s)=y(s)=v(s)=0$ then I cannot do anything and the proof stoped here.

Comment: @RH1 But then $x(s)=u(s)$ and $y(s)=v(s)$, so the rest of the proof should be *exactly the same* as what you claim to have already proved. If this doesn't work, there is a problem with the original proof of (P).

Comment: @  Matt Pressland: No, there is no problem. I am just confused about the existsence of zero in the begining. I imagine that if $x(s)=u(s)=y(s)=v(s)=0$ then I cannot do anything else.